# Client Report Definition (.rdlc) Textbox vertical align text

Tags: c#, reporting-services

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 and have created a Client Report Definition (.rdlc).

In this report I add a single Textbox and double it's height. When I change the TextAlign to "Center" it correctly centers the text, but when I set the VerticalAlign to "Middle" nothing happens. The textbox is big enough that it's obviously not aligned to the middle. Any ideas on why this happens and how to fix it?

Comment: What you described works fine for me. Do you have padding set correctly?

Comment: I didn't have the report viewer window setup yet, so I was basing this question on the design time behavior. TextAlign "center" works in the designer. However, VerticalAlign "Middle" doesn't. I was basing my findings on the design time behavior. Several other properties don't work in the designer but show up correctly once the report is ran.

Comment: I have a similar problem. What are correct padding settings to make it work?

Comment: Just make sure the top and bottom padding is the same.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. The curious part of it is that two columns of the table display the text correctly -- vertically aligned to the middle -- while the other three columns display the text aligned to the top.

The single difference I found in the settings of the two correct textboxes vs the three incorrect textboxes is the Format field.
The textboxes that align correctly have Format property set to "F4", while the other three textboxes have nothing there.

For starters I tried changing the Format property for only one of three and then *all three* are now displayed OK.

Answer (score 0):

Try this using jquery after you load the report.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('*[id*=oReportCell]').closest("table").css("margin", "auto");
 $('*[id*=oReportCell]').css("vertical-align", "middle");
});
```